# Parallel processes in bash

Tags: python, bash, multithreading, algorithm, scheduled-tasks

I have two bash scripts: `p1` and `p2`. The first one `p1` lasts 40 seconds, and when it ends I would like to run `p2`.

Then, I would like to repeat this pattern parallel every 2 seconds. Here is a diagram to better illustrate what I would like:

[image]

How can I achieve this ? Preferably in bash but if not possible I can use python and run my bash scripts using subprocess for example.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`while true; do; ( p1; p2 ) &; sleep 2; done`

To avoid annoying "Done" printouts:
`while true; do; ( ( p1; p2 ) & ); sleep 2; done`

Obviously, you can modify to use `&&` or `|` as appropriate.

If you don't mind waiting the 2 seconds at beginning before the first run, you can replace `while true` with `while sleep 2` which would look better, but waste time at the start.

Comment: Thanks! It does exactly what I would like!

Answer (score 1):

Every two seconds, start p1 followed by p2 in the background:

```sh
while sleep 2
do
  p1 && p2 &
done
```

Comment: From what I see `p1 && p2` should be inside a parenthesis to achieve the requirement of running in parallel.

Comment: @MariosMitalidis I think this is correct. `p1 && p2 &` is the same as `{ p1 && p2; } &`. You can try this with `{ sleep 1; echo a; } && { sleep 1; echo b; } &`.

Comment: Thanks! It does exactly what I would like!

Comment: hi @Socowi, I can see how this answer runs p1 and then p2, however, it should be starting pairs of processes in parallel. 
For example:
````bash
while sleep 2 ; do { sleep 5; echo -n "p1: "; date } && { sleep 5; echo -n "p2: "; date } & ;done
p1: Sat  8 May 2021 20:19:26 BST
p2: Sat  8 May 2021 20:19:31 BST
p1: Sat  8 May 2021 20:19:33 BST
p2: Sat  8 May 2021 20:19:38 BST
````

Comment: whereas I would expect:
````bash
while sleep 2 ; do ({ sleep 5; echo -n "p1: "; date } && { sleep 5; echo -n "p2: "; date }) & ;done
p1: Sat  8 May 2021 20:20:23 BST
p1: Sat  8 May 2021 20:20:25 BST
p1: Sat  8 May 2021 20:20:27 BST
p2: Sat  8 May 2021 20:20:28 BST
p1: Sat  8 May 2021 20:20:29 BST
p2: Sat  8 May 2021 20:20:30 BST
p1: Sat  8 May 2021 20:20:31 BST
p2: Sat  8 May 2021 20:20:32 BST
````

Comment: @MariosMitalidis But this answer *is* starting pairs of processes in parallel. It seems like you didn't actually ran your commands since they contain syntax errors. For the first command, you claimed the output would be `p1 p2 p1 p2 ...` when in fact it is `p1 p1 ... p2 p2` for both of your commands. As I said: `a && b &` is the same as `{ a && b; } &`. The braces (in your case parenthesis) around both commands are not necessary. OP even confirmed that this answer does what they wanted.

Comment: @Socowi you are right, thanks for the reply. I was testing this in zsh which has different behaviour to bash. That was a mistake on my side. This question is relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162286/precedence-of-vs-in-bash-and-zsh